# Outgoing Mail not working after changing port 25

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, postfix, firewall

I want to block Port 25 as my IP got blacklisted multiple times due to some spammers using my server.
I've changed the Port to 578 in Postfix and restarted postfix & on top I've as well changed the smtp_port to 578 and restarted nginx.

However, when I DENY OUT Port 25 as well my own mails don't get sent out despite I've additionally explicitly set ALLOW OUT for Port 578.

It would be great in case you could help me block spammers & make my mail work

Comment: Show the mail logs and your postfix config.  It is unclear what you are trying to block exactly - what difference does allowing port 578 make if your server is running on 3625?  In any event you probably want to allow `localhost` connections.

Comment: Ups, sorry, I've once used port 3625 and then changed it 578. I am currently testing it just with 578 and it doesn't work when finally blocking Port 25

Comment: You can't change the outgoing port. The port is determined by the server that receives the mail. If the receiving server only accepts mails on Port 25 there is nothing you can do to change that.

Comment: Thanks, I've just found that out as well. I was irritated by some pages telling that changing this port would prevemt spammers using the server

Comment: If some spammers are using your server you have more serious problems than an open TCP port.